# AWS Machine Learning Service in .NET Core

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, machine-learning, .net-core, aws-lambda

I'd like to do a prediction in .NET Core on AWS Lambda using the Machine Learning service provided by AWS . I am getting this error. Does anyone have information about it?

https://prnt.sc/r1buou

```
Error   CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type
'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Amazon.MachineLearning.Model.Prediction>' to
'Amazon.MachineLearning.Model.Prediction'
```

Comment: It looks like you aren't doing an `await` on the method you are calling.

Comment: I've developed earlier in the C# Environment Now, instead of Predict .NET Core Environment PredictAsync there is only one CancellationToken from me wants to solve .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are building .NET Core Lambda functions you are using the .NET Standard version of the AWS SDK for .NET. The .NET Standard version only supports async operations due to that is what the underlying HttpClient supports in .NET Standard. So when you use the SDK in Lambda you will have to use .NET async/await pattern when making calls. The .NET Framework version, which you are probably more used to, supports sync as well as aync method.

Comment: Çok teşekkür ederim Norm Johanson çözüldü !